# Move to next cell in Excel.Range in a foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, excel, foreach, vba

I have an excel.range called rng. I iterate through it using a foreach loop.

```
foreach(Excel.Range cell in rng)
{
   //do something
}
```

The foreach loop is very useful in my application and *I cannot use a for loop*. Now to my question:

**Is there any way to move to the i:th cell relative to the current cell?** And continue my foreach loop from that cell. Like this:

```
foreach(Excel.Range cell in rng)
{
    If(cell.value.ToString() == "Something")
       //move 3 cells forward in rng relative to the current cell
}
```

I'm not looking for the continue; expression. I need to move forward in my range somehow. How I do it is less important. It could be a loop using some kind of moveNext() command or some kind of indexing.

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Are you looking for the `OFFSET` function? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You want to move to the adjacent cell of next column OR

To the next cell of same column?

Comment: Or do you want to "skip" the next three times of the foreach loop?(that you could do with a for loop, but you've already said in this case you can't)

Comment: The Offset property don't seem to work in my case. I've tried using rng = rng.Ofsett[3, 0]; but in the next loops it still uses the next cell relative to the previous cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, there's no way to "skip ahead" an arbitrary number of items within a `foreach` loop. Not being able to use a `for` loop is a bizarre requirement so I'm wondering if this is a puzzle and not a real problem. But I digress...

Remember that each access to an Excel property in C# is a COM call, so it is *very expensive*.  You will get better performance (and make your programming easier) by pulling the entire range into an array:

```
object[,] data = rng.Value2 as object[,];
```

The array will contain strings (for text cells) and doubles (for numeric/date cells).  THen you can use standard loops to navigate the array.  When you;'re done, just put the data back:

```
rng.Value2 = data;
```

Comment: there's not an real way to skip ahead, but you can kind of "control it" with an if statement and a int variable...

Comment: I will consider this! The reason I don't want to use a for loop is that I've had a lot of problems with blank or empty cells when parsing my Excel column. To be more precise, I use a special command to only read the non empty cells but when using a for loop these cells are still there, causing a lot of trouble. When using a foreach loop my program only consider the non empty cells in my range. Also I use the other properties of the range object frequently, like cell.Row, cell.Column, cell.Value etc. Ofc this could also be stored in a object array.

Comment: @kPuck Okay that makes more sense.  The gist is to keep the number of method and property calls to a minimum.  if you can use an array in memory and infer the `Row` and `Column` you will have significantly better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question it seems that you need answer for "How to refer adjacent cells?"

For that you can use Offset() property in excel vba.

It works like this: Assume you are referring to Row no. 1 of column A. Now you want to refer same row but column D; you can use:

Range("Your_Range").Offset(0, 3).Select

For more on OFFSET function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to skip the foreach, in this case, you could do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(Excel.Range cell in rng)
{
  if(i>0)
  {
    i--;
  }
  else
  {
    if(cell.value.ToString() == "Something")
      i=3;
  }
```

with that you'd be "skipping" the foreach, but still, try to use a for loop instead, it would be much more simple than this